# numbering questions in

Tags: enumerate

I have to put my research questions in latex overleaf. Question 1. and then there are two more questions emerging from this question which I want to state as a. and b. After this I want to go back to question 2 and 3. Now can someone help me with this? I am trying \begin{enumerate} and then `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]` but there is error msg. I also `\end{enumerate}` after a. and b. and `\end{enumerate}` at the end. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please show the code for what you've already done, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  (Show only the packages that are relevant to the problem.)  Also please show the exact error message.  We need more information to be able to help.

Comment: Welcome. // To better decide how to keep your code simple, complete and meaningful to show your problem, you may want to follow these steps to arrive at such a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137

Comment: Do you use the `enumerate` or the `enumitem` package? Please advise.